# How do I move my nav bar up below the logo and make it stay there?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm currently creating a website just to mess with CSS and HTML, however, I've ran into a problem with my navigation bar. I've created it, however, when I put my logo in at the top of the page, above the nav bar, the nav bar moved down to like the middle of the page and I'm not sure how to move it so that it's just below the logo. From what I remember this happened when I put in another image which I haven't positioned at that point, but even after moving that image, the nav bar didn't move back to its original point. I tried setting the position of it to fixed, but it moved it to the left side of the screen.

And also, how would I go about moving the second image within my website without ruining the nav bar again?

Here is my CSS:

```
#image1 {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: 8%;
width: 30%;
}

#image2 {
position: relative;
width: 20%;
top: 400px;
right: 481px;

}
ul {
list-style-type:none;
width:60%;
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: rgba(163,21,23,1.00)
}

li {
float: right;
width: 33.33%;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
border: thin;
border-style: groove;
}

li a:hover {
background-color: #111;
}

body {
background-color: rgba(96,96,96,1.00)
}
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>    LoL    </title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>  
<img src="assets/lol.png" alt="Logo" id="image1">
<img src="assets/minions.png" alt="Minions in LoL" id="image2" >

<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="#Home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#Farming">Farming</a></li>
<li><a href="#Best champions for each role">Best champions for each role</a>
</li>
</ul>
<banner></banner>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want your logo and nav bar in same horizontal line ?

Comment: The same but one above each other, so the logo first in the top, middle of the page, and then right underneath it the nav bar. I've got this done, but when I insert any other image, they just completely move the nav bar along with them.

Comment: Edit - i've fixed it. All it required was to change the positioning of the <img for the second image in the HTML, as I originally had it above the nav bar. Honestly didn't think this would've been the problem :D

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS for image 1, change the height from a percentage to pixels. (Say 150px)

```
Image1 { height: 150px; }
```

Then with your ul element try putting

```
Ul {
Top: 150px;
Display: Fixed;
}
```

That should sit the Nav bar right under the logo!

Use the development tools in your browser to see what happening.
I.E margin forcing it down etc. 
On chrome you can right click and "inspect element".

Comment: So I've managed to put the right under each other, but my problem now is that when I put in any more images, it just completely moves the nav bar and I can't get it back to its original position. When I put in position:fixed , it moved it to the right.

Comment: Edit - i've fixed it. All it required was to change the positioning of the <img for the second image in the HTML, as I originally had it above the nav bar. Honestly didn't think this would've been the problem :D